# tabularx within the enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate, tabularx

does someone know how to set the width of the tabularx table to the width of the text inside `\item` in the enumerate environment? `\textwidth` doesn't account for the environment

Answer (score 6):

The width of the line varies from place to place within a document and is stored inside `\linewidth`. `\textwidth` remains constant as the width of the text block, but certain environments don't use this entire width; most notably lists (like `enumerate` or `itemize`). Here's an example, with the text block highlighted to show the effects:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\newcommand{\settable}[1]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{#1}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    abc & def \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}}
\begin{document}

Regular indentation:

\settable{\textwidth} \par\medskip

\settable{\linewidth} \par\bigskip

No indentation

\noindent\settable{\textwidth} \par\medskip

\noindent\settable{\linewidth} \par\bigskip

Inside a list:

\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \settable{\textwidth} \par\medskip

  \item
  \settable{\linewidth}
\end{itemize}

Double nested list:

\begin{itemize}
  \item
  \begin{itemize}
    \item
    \settable{\textwidth} \par\medskip

    \item
    \settable{\linewidth}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Inside lists, `\linewidth` is properly set to be the "adjusted" width of the text block.

Comment: thank u for the answer! and what could u suggest for tabularx within table (then again it's so wide)? so that caption could be used

Comment: @user2339479: Within a `table`, there is no indent. However, `\linewidth` still functions as expected (being equivalent to `\textwidth`). So, you can still use it.